# MacPort Meld not working on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macports, meld

On my system running Big Sur, I successfully installed MacPorts and meld. But when I run meld, I get the following error

% meld
2022-04-07 17:36:21,148 CRITICAL Gtk: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
2022-04-07 17:36:21,148 CRITICAL Gtk: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
2022-04-07 17:36:21,148 CRITICAL Gtk: _gtk_style_provider_private_get_settings: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIVATE (provider)' failed
zsh: segmentation fault  meld

I have verified that gtk2/gtk3 are installed. Do I need to install any other package like quartz or xorg?

thanks for your help